# VS Code: module and GOPATH usage and settings

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, gopath

I recently rearranged my VS Code workspace. Before rearranging it I had no problems neither with Go modules nor $GOPATH. Now I have adopted the much beloved hexagonal project layout as I find it quite organized and I like it a lot better than what I had before. I created my projects subdirectory within the src subdirectory of my $GOPATH. Now whenever I create a new project file within this projects subdirectory VS Code presents me with the following message: "You are neither in a module nor in your GOPATH. If you are using modules, please open your editor at the directory containing the go.mod. If you believe this warning is incorrect, please file an issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new.". I have no idea how to fix the issue and would appreciate any help or feedback! What seems strange to me is that i can run`go run` without any sort of problem.

> Just to clarify my workspace is set up as: $GOPATH\src\projects\cmd, internal, pkg and the main.go file I am trying to run is in cmd\project1\main.go

Go env results:

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Niccolo\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\Niccolo\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Niccolo\code\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Niccolo\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build787404170=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a monorepo, if yes, the go language server does not work propely. you will need to open a vscode workspace on that project path

Comment: Thanks @RonalCarvalho, I totally forgot about asking the question as I just restarted my PC and everything seemed to work probably. It must have been some type of bug having to do with the reorganization